# Windows.h CONDITION_VARIABLE causes exception (C/C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, condition-variable

I'm having trouble with very basic Windows programming, implementing a simple producer/consumer system.

My struct:

```
typedef struct FILE_BUFFER { //Circular buffer of max size BUF_SIZE
    INT count;            //buffer size 
    LPTSTR buf[BUF_SIZE]; //actual buffer of file names

    BOOL stopRequested; //Exit flag

    LPCRITICAL_SECTION lock; //Synch stuff
    PCONDITION_VARIABLE notEmpty;
    PCONDITION_VARIABLE notFull;
}FILE_BUFFER;

FILE_BUFFER fb;
```

my init function (ran in main thread)

```
VOID init() {
    fb.stopRequested = FALSE;
    fb.count = 0;
    InitializeCriticalSection(fb.lock);
    InitializeConditionVariable(fb.notEmpty);
    InitializeConditionVariable(fb.notFull);
}
```

The init function cause exception to be thrown on the InitializeConditionVariable instruction, of type Access Violation (ntdll.dll).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and compiling for Windows x64

Thanks

Comment: You have to allocate the critical section object. change `LPCRITICAL_SECTION lock;` to `CRITICAL_SECTION lock;`  and pass `&fb.lock` to `InitializeCriticalSection`

Comment: *I'm using Visual Studio 2017* and this is tagged c++. Have a look at std::vector< std::string > instead of LPSTR, and std::mutex, std::condition_variable, std::lock_guard and all the other goodies: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Comment: System Hungarian to the rescue.  Type names that start with P are pointers.  Those pointers are not pointing to anything.

Comment: Damn I knew it was something stupid.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

You are passing uninitialized pointers as parameters to `InitializeCriticalSection` and `InitializeConditionVariable`. You should allocate appropriate structures and pass a pointer to them instead:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION lock; //Synch stuff
CONDITION_VARIABLE notEmpty;
CONDITION_VARIABLE notFull;
```

...

```
InitializeCriticalSection(&(fb.lock));
InitializeConditionVariable(&(fb.notEmpty));
InitializeConditionVariable(&(fb.notFull));
```

Comment: And don't forget to release the critical section when you are done using it: `DeleteCriticalSection(&(fb.lock));`.   You don't need to release the condition variables (there is no API function to do it anyway). Look at MSDN's [Using Condition Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903.aspx) example : "*The following code implements a producer/consumer queue.*"